# QuickOSM - display timestamp of resulting OSM objects

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

When entering the **QuickOSM** query or even after running the query in the QuickOSM plugin for QGIS, I cannot find any information on the resulting layers apart from the values in the attribute table.

**Where can I find the date from the time it was uploaded and/or last updated?**
Without that, it is hard to say how current and useful the data is.

Comment: You should include just one question. Create a separate post for each question. See [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main window of QuickOSM go to the `Advanced` section and tick `Metadata` (see screenshot below). In your resulting layers you will then find the attribute `osm_timestamp` which indicates the timestamp on which the OSM object was updated the last time.

[image: screenshot of QuickOSM plugin]